# Make sum of two Bernoulli random variables to be a Bernoulli random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a Bernoulli r.v. $X$ with $p$. I would like to add a random variable $Y$ with parameter $b$ so that $X + Y$ is also a Bernoulli distribution with $p + b$. Any hints on what $Y$ should be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a pair of discrete random variables with joint PMF $f_{X,Y}(0,0)=1-(p+b),f_{X,Y}(1,0)=p,f_{X,Y}(0,1)=b$.

A nice way to construct such a thing is to let $\omega$ be uniform on $[0,1]$, then let $X=\begin{cases} 1 & \omega \in [0,p) \\ 0 & \omega \in [p,1] \end{cases}$ and $Y=\begin{cases} 0 & \omega \in [0,p) \\ 1 & \omega \in [p,p+b) \\ 0 & \omega \in [p+b,1] \end{cases}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What happens when $b$ is negative?

Comment: @JLB Yes, the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are Bernoulli(p) and Bernoulli(b) respectively.

Comment: How is $Y$ defined when $\omega \in [0,p)$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Oops, easy fix. Thanks. (I guess I should've just done written "otherwise" instead of being explicit like this...)